# Interruptable Java Console app

Tags: java, console, signals, terminate

I am writing a console app which potentially will run for days and days. To give my computer some downtime so to speak, I need the app to be interruptable, but in such a way that it will only stop at certain well defined points during its execution.

I decided to use a signal-handler to trap CTRL+C, but it behaves in a way I cannot get my head around.

What I want is something like this:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    class MySignalHandler implements SignalHandler
    {
        boolean interrupted = false;

        public void handle( Signal signal )
        {
            interrupted = true;
        }
    }

    MySignalHandler env = new MySignalHandler();
    Signal.handle( new Signal( "INT" ), env );

    while ( ! env.interrupted )
    {
        ... Carry out a small and well-defined portion of the overall process ...
    }
}
```

This doesn't work (at least not from my Windows command-prompt). The app never terminates.

However if I change the while-loop to look like this:

```
while (true)
    if (env.interrupted)
        System.out.print( "Y" );
    else
        System.out.print( "N" );
```

... and run the app from the command-prompt, I get the following effect:
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN (Now I press CTRL+C) YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

Clearly the signal is trapped by the code, so I don't see why the original while-loop will not terminate. I would very much appreciate some help. Maybe I've overlooked something obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `interrupted` to communicate between threads but haven't told the compiler that, so it is "simplifying" your `while` loop by only checking once. Make `interrupted` `volatile`.

Comment: So the condition on an if-statement is always re-evaluated, whereas the condition on a while-statement isn't.

Comment: @MadsBoyd-Madsen That's not necessarily true. In C, this sort of thing is notoriously dependent on optimization level, and AFAIK the JLS wouldn't forbid optimizing it out. You're just running into undefined behavior by using an ordinary variable to communicate between threads.